# Содержит ли данное предложение повествование?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Если не
доступно решение государственных вопросов, что повышает всегда уровень 
счастья, если они мудро решаются, то повысить этот уровень счастья можно 
в пределах своего рабочего окружения, в пределах своей школы, в кругу 
своих друзей и товарищей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Повествование** — это рассказ, сообщение о каком-либо событии в его временной последовательности. Поэтому нет здесь повествования, это рассуждение.

**Рассуждение** — ряд мыслей, суждений, умозаключений на какую-нибудь тему, изложенных в логически последовательной форме.

В принципе мысль понятна, но **четкой и последовательной логики в построении текста нет,** требуется доработка.

**В качестве варианта:**

Если недоступно решение государственных вопросов (а успешная деятельность такого рода повышает уровень  счастья человека), то достигнуть более высокого уровня можно в пределах своего рабочего окружения, в своей школе, в кругу своих друзей и товарищей.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая подсказочка: Повествование можно разбить на цепь отдельных событий, которые можно заснять на отдельные файлы. (Мы ведь в повествовании выделяем сюжет: завязку, развитие действия, кульминацию, развязку)

Описание - предмет описания можно заснять на один файл и перечислить детали картинки. Если даже это описание чувства, всё равно есть детали одного образа.

Рассуждение - речь, её заснять нельзя,это сообщение о причинах и следствиях событий и явлений,о наших представлениях о них, оценках, чувствах.Его элементы: вступление, тезис, доказательства, вывод (не все элементы обязательны)

Ваш пример как раз рассуждение: причинно-следственные связи налицо, заснять события невозможно, событий нет, есть только рассуждения о них.